# Screenshot Issue After Upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, screenshot, 18.10, gnome-screenshot

This issue appeared after I upgrade my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10.

I can't take any screenshot by pressing the screenshot hotkeys, It will make the screen hanging for a few second, the sidebar and menu bar is also disappear. But it's still possible to take a screenshot by using the apps, not by pressing the screenshot hotkeys. This is the screenshot when I take it using the screenshot apps:

[image: Screenshot taken with the screenshot apps]

**Edit:**

Somewhat the screenshot apps went normally after a shutdown and try  to change the screenshot hotkeys (Settings->Device->Keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

I went to the settings and reconfigured the Shortcuts. Then it worked for me.
[image: keyboard config]

Comment: I don't know if this solve the issue, but when I try to change the hotkey, the screenshot suddenly went normal (Haven't change the hotkey though)